# Water will not boil at a higher temperature at a higher altitude. - Is "will not" correct here?

Tags: usage

We can use "will" to express that something is habitual or factual.

Does this kind of usage have negative forms?

**Example 1**

> Water will boil at a lower temperature at a higher altitude.

**Example 2**

> Water **will not** boil at a higher temperature at a higher altitude.

**Example 3**

> Tom will get home before sunrise at the weekends.

**Example 4**

> Tom **won't** get home before sunrise at the weekends.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use "will" and its negative form "won't" to talk about negative habits or facts. All of your example sentences are grammatically correct.

Comment: Things will not burn in a nitrogen atmosphere; cardboard will not stop bullets; my cat will not eat iron filings.

Comment: I'm no physicist, but (2) doesn't make sense to me (though it is grammatical). The point of sentence (1) is that it takes less heat to boil water at high altitudes, not that it won't continue boiling at a higher temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples 1 and 2 are correct: this is the use of *will* to express "propensities." It is particularly common when you can also express the same idea using a conditional. You can do so in this case: "if you are at a higher altitude, water will boil at a lower temperature." That aside, you can also use the simple present here.

Examples 3 and 4 are also correct. These are harder to rephrase as conditionals, so if you're describing Tom's ongoing tendencies or propensities, the simple present would be somewhat preferred. That said, you could use these sentences to describe Tom's *decision* to go home before sunrise in the future. This is the use of *will* to describe "volition."

(My source for this is Huddleston & Pullum (2002), chapter 3, §9.5.1-2.)